# odd even file renaming powershell v.2

Tags: powershell

How to rename files with sequential even and odd numbers in PowerShell?
The 2 answers from Avshalom and Matt work well. I scan old historical books by camera and need a way to start the renaming from the middle of the book, say page 62, not from page 1 but still keep the odd-even numbering system. For example rename page_62, page_64, page_66. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi, I tried the script you sent me and added the $Path = "C:\test

Comment: Hi, I tried the script you sent me and added  $Path= "c:\test  but didn't get it to work. I have some files I could send you to try if that would help. Roger

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

```
$Pages = Get-ChildItem "*.jpg" | Sort Name
$PageCounter = 0

for ($i=62;$i-lt$MaxPages;$i+=2){
    $PageToRename = $Pages[$PageCounter]
    $PageCounter++
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $PageToRename.FullName -NewName "Page $($i)"
}
```

Comment: Hi, I ran the script you gave me:

Comment: @germandog I'm assuming you meant to put something else in there? you'll need to edit this slightly depending on your situation, it wont run as-is.